# How To Use OnClick Function In jQuery From MVC View Foreach

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a question on jQuery onClick function with foreach using.(I am new on jQuery.)

```
<table>
  <th>CityName</th>
  <th>CityId</th>
  @foreach (var item in Model.Adress)
  {   
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div onClick(cityDetail(@item.CityId, @item.cityName))>@CityId</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>@CityName</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  }
</table>

<script> 
  function cityDetail(cityId, cityName) {
    //do something
  }
</script>
```

My question is that, how can I do this only with jQuery?
 `onClick(cityDetail(@item.CityId,@item.cityName)`. I want to use foreach and pass clicked multiple parameters to jQuery.

Thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's generally a good idea to avoid all `on*` event attributes as it ties the HTML and JS code together too tightly. Instead, attach event handlers using unobtrusive Javascript. You can pass the `CityId` and `CityName` values to the event handler through `data` attributes on the elements created in the loop.

Also note that your HTML has some issues, such as a missing `<tr>` around the `th`, and the column headings in the wrong order to the data underneath.

With all that said, try this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('.city').click(function() {
      var $city = $(this);
      cityDetail($city.data('city-id'), $city.data('city-name'));
    });
  });
</script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>City Id</th>
    <th>City Name</th>
  </tr>
  @foreach (var item in Model.Adress) {
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="city" data-city-id="@item.CityId" data-city-name="@item.cityName">@item.CityId</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>@item.cityName</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  }
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, this is very helpfull :D

Comment: No problem, glad to help